# make bash printf consider array as one argument

Tags: linux, bash

On ubuntu-14.04, bash-4.3.11, I run this:

```
$ _array=(1 2 3)
$ echo "${_array[@]} bloup"
1 2 3 bloup
$ printf "%s bloup\n" "${_array[@]}"
1 bloup
2 bloup
3 bloup
```

- How can I make printf *behave* as echo in this situation?
- Why does printf consider the *double-quoted* array as three arguments? i.e. what expansion mechanism am I missing here?

As a workaround, I use this:

```
$ _string=${_array[@]}
$ printf "%s bloup\n" "$_string"
1 2 3 bloup
```

Comment: If you use it double quoted with `[*]` it will expand to a single argument. `printf "%s bloup\n" "${_array[*]}"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use `*` in place of `@`:

```
printf "%s bloup\n" "${_array[*]}"
```

The purpose of `@` is to make treat the expansion as separate quoted words for each element, so that the expansion of an array like `("a b" c d)` is treated as 3 arguments, not 4.